# Problems injecting a custom service using Roboguice

Tags: android, roboguice

I just started playing around with Roboguice and I'm trying to inject one of my services in an activity or fragment. What happens is that my service is just instantiated and injected as a POJO and no lifecycle methods are called which makes me suspect I forgot to do something. However I could only find examples of well-known service being injected.

The service looks something like this:

```
public class ProgramService extends RoboService {

public ProgramService() {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "instantiating service " + hashCode());
}

public class Binder extends android.os.Binder {
    public ProgramService getService() {
        return ProgramService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "binding service " + hashCode());
    return new Binder();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "creating service " + hashCode());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "destroying service " + hashCode());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "starting service " + hashCode());
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

And my activity looks something like this:

```
public class ProgramListActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity implements
    ProgramListFragment.Callbacks {

private boolean mTwoPane;

@Inject
private ProgramService programService;
...
```

And the service is declared in the manifest as follows:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name=".ProgramService"></service>
```

The only log output I get is that of "instantiating service".

What do I have to do so Roboguice knows that ProgramService is not a POJO but a service? I must be missing something rather basic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the actual (now skipped) class declaration of ProgramService with what classes/interfaces it extends?